# How to update table with multiple columns condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get result from table in another database.

My code is

```
Declare @customer table (name, custno, address)

Insert into @customer (custno, address)
values (1, Madrid)

Declare @account table (custno, accno, accbalance)

Insert into @account (custno, accno)
values (1, 2)

Declare @transaction table (accno, accbalance, address)

Insert into @transaction (accno, amount)
values (2, 2)
```

Now I want to set

```
@transaction.address = @customer.address
```

I still don't find the way to do this.

I expect output when

```
select * from @transaction
```

The result is

```
2 | 2 | Madrid
```

Comment: What "other database" are you talking about?  Isn't the solution a simple `join`?

Comment: Considering that these are variables as well, no databases are really involved. These variables are only going to persist for the duration of the batch, and if they are going to be written to disc (unlikely considering the small amount of data, so they're likely persist in RAM), they'll all be written within `tempdb`. So, at most, there is only 1 database involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think thises query can be respond :

```
    Declare @customer table
(name varchar(50),custno int,address varchar(50))
Insert into @customer (custno,address)
 values (1, 'Madrid')
Declare @class table
 (custno int,accno int,accbalance int)
Insert into @class (custno,accno)
 values (1,2)
Declare @transaction table
 (accno int,amount int ,address varchar(50))
Insert into @transaction (accno,amount)
 values (2,2)


 select * from @customer

 select * from @class

 select * from @transaction


 Update tr set tr.address = cs.address from @transaction as tr join @class as cl on cl.accno = tr.accno JOIN @customer as cs on cs.custno = cl.custno 


 select * from @transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you to use directly the data from the original source in Customer table, so:

```
Declare @customer table
(   [name] VARCHAR(10),
    custno VARCHAR(10),
    address VARCHAR(10))

Insert into @customer (custno, address)
 values (1, 'Madrid')

Declare @account table
 (  custno INT,
    accno VARCHAR(10),
    accbalance VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @account (custno,accno)
 values (1,2)

Declare @transaction table
 (  accno INT,
    accbalance VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @transaction (accno,accbalance)
 values (2,2);
```

And... query would include the 3 tables instead of only Transaction:

```
 SELECT T.accno, T.accbalance, C.address 
    FROM @transaction T
    INNER JOIN @account A
        ON A.accno = T.accno
    INNER JOIN @customer C
        ON C.custno = A.custno;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update with join like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.address = c.address
FROM @transaction t
INNER JOIN @account a
    ON t.accno = a.accno
INNER JOIN @customer c
    ON a.custno = c.custno
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `join`. Remember when updating with join you need to define table name as `alias` as shown below.

```
Declare @customer table
(name varchar(20),custno varchar(20),[address] varchar(20))

Insert into @customer (custno,[address])
 values (1, 'Madrid')

Declare @class table
 (custno varchar(20), accno varchar(20), accbalance int)

Insert into @class (custno,accno)
 values (1,2)

Declare @transaction table
 (accno varchar(20), accbalance int, [address] varchar(20))

Insert into @transaction (accno,accbalance)
 values (2,2)

UPDATE t 
SET [address] = c.[address]
FROM @transaction as t
INNER JOIN @class as cl on t.accno = cl.accno
INNER JOIN @customer as c
       ON c.custno = cl.custno

select * from @transaction
```

The output is as shown below.

```
accno   accbalance  address
---------------------------
2       2           Madrid
```